# Hyperledger and ICO token

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum

Is it possible to make interact a `ERC20` token with a `hyperledger` permissioned `blockchain`? I would like to have my private `blockchain` and then be able to the participants use that token on that `blockchain`.

or theres any other alternative to accomplish that?